# Power Query get files from folders with files with different numbers of columns able to be refreshed

Tags: excel, powerquery

So my goal is to have one folder where we can dump all the files we get daily. Then I would like to just hit a refresh on a power query to update a list. My issue is the files have different numbers of columns depending on which tests we did the previous day and I'm interested in only results from "set 1" "set 2" and "set 3". It gets more frustrating because the file is sent to us with about 8 rows above the useful data and the column headers above the data are 1 row above where you would like it. Eg of data set 1.

[image: data set 1]

The second set of data would look like this:

[image: data set 2]

I am trying to get it to look like this as an output:

[image: data set 3]

I have tried to combine and transform, then change the step before they are combined to remove the pesky floating rows, fill up the number header and remove the empty row below the headers. Then the data gets appended. Any repeating value under the column number was being an issue because I need all individual values but when I removed duplicates it would remove the row with data. I fixed that by putting the output of the query into a pivot table and that seemed to work okay. Then I threw another data sheet in the folder and when I refreshed the query it said a column of the table wasn't found. I have looked through similar issues where there were different numbers of columns and they append empty columns, but I need an automatic solution. Is there a way to do this or am I on a fools errand?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the change type step and everything seemed to work more or less.